# How do I make certain mobs in minecraft not spawn?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I'm trying to make it work but it doesn't want to.

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent event) {
        /* Put all mobs that you don't want to spawn into an array */
        EntityType[] blacklist = {
                EntityType.VEX
        };

        /* Then loop through the array */
        for(int i = 0; i < blacklist.length; i++)
            if(event.getEntityType() == blacklist[i]){
                event.setCancelled(true);
            }
    }
}*/`
```

I was expecting another action like the vexes not spawning but they actually spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a spigot question?

If so, try this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onSpawn(EntitySpawnEvent event) {
    Entity entity = event.getEntity();
    if (entity.getType() == EntityType.VEX)
        event.setCancelled(true);
}
```

If you want to blacklist more mobs, in the if statement either do an '||'. It  would look like this:

```
if(entity.getType() == EntityType.VEX || entity.getType() == EntityType.ZOMBIE)
```

If it is a large list of mobs, you can probably do something like this:

```
blacklist[] = ["VEX, "ZOMBIE", "COW"]
if(Arrays.asList(blacklist).contains(entity.getType()))
```

Comment: actually its a bukkit server

Comment: Ah. If what I recommended doesn't work still I would have to check the bukkit docs. I thought bukkit was discontinued though, no?

Comment: meh ik bukkit is discountinued but isnt purpur and pufferfish like bukkit?